# Как найти строку при нескольких параметрах redbeanphp?

Tags: php, redbeanphp

Надо найти строку по 3 параметрам (таблица communications)
фильтры

```
idcontact1 = $result1
idcontact2 = $_COOKIE['id']
status = 2
```

так выглядит поиск строки
(по 1 параметру нельзя, тк будет найдено несколько строк)
 R::findOne( 'settings', ' id = ? ',array($_COOKIE['id']));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
R::findOne('settings', ' id = :id AND status = :status ', [':id' => $_COOKIE['id'], ':status' => 'STATUS']);
```

Comment: не работает (..

Comment: @ДенисЛебедев попутал фреймворки :) исправил свой ответ

Comment: правильно вдь вроде?  $fasas = R::findOne('communications', ' idcontact2 = :idcontact2 AND status = :status AND idcontact1= :idcontact1', [':idcontact2' => $_COOKIE['id'], ':status' => '2', ':idcontact1' => $sdasd->aliasid]);